# Localizing extension descriptions before Gecko 1.9

Tags: localization, firefox-addon, gecko

I'm trying to build an extension for Firefox with localized name basing on information from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Localizing_extension_descriptions (Localizing before Gecko 1.9), but it doesn't work. The error in the browser's Javascript console is:

```
Błąd: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER) [nsIRDFService.GetLiteral]"  nsresult: "0x80004003 (NS_ERROR_INVALID_POINTER)"  location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox%201.5/components/nsExtensionManager.js :: EM_L :: line 225"  data: no]
Plik źródłowy: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox%201.5/components/nsExtensionManager.js
Wiersz: 225
```

My extension files hierarchy is:

```
gemgecko.xpi:
              /install.rdf                   
              /components/gemgecko.dll                   
              /defaults/preferences/prefs.js                          
              /chrome.manifest                  
              /chrome/locale/pl/install.properties
              /chrome/locale/en/install.properties
```

**/defaults/preferences/prefs.js:**

```
pref("extensions.gemgecko@gemius.pl.name", "chrome://gemgecko/locale/en/install.properties");
```

**/chrome/locale/en/install.properties:**

```
extensions.gemgecko@gemius.pl.name=gemiusAudience study
```

**/chrome/locale/pl/install.properties:**

```
extensions.gemgecko@gemius.pl.name=Badanie Megapanel PBI/Gemius
```

Can anybody help me to find an error in my extension?

**Edit**

I'm adding install manifest...

**/install.rdf:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
<Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>gemgecko@gemius.pl</em:id>
    <em:version>2.01</em:version>
    <em:name>nazwa</em:name>
    <em:creator>tworca</em:creator>
    <em:description>opis</em:description>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.test.pl</em:homepageURL>

    <em:targetApplication>
        <Description>
            <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id> <!-- firefox -->
            <em:minVersion>1.5.0</em:minVersion>
            <em:maxVersion>*</em:maxVersion>
        </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

</Description>

</RDF>
```

I've tested it on Firefox 1.5 and 3.6. On 3.6 everything seems to work OK, but on 1.5 doesn't - the extension manager displays the extension's name from `install.rdf` not from `chrome://gemgecko/locale/install.properties`...

Comment: You could also post your chrome.manifest but I think Neil is right on.

Comment: chrome.manifest:
binary-component components/gemgecko4.dll appversion>=4.-1
binary-component components/gemgecko.dll appversion<4.-1
category profile-after-change "NetPanel extension for Gecko based browsers." @gemius.pl/NPMOZILLA appversion>=4.-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome://gemgecko/locale/en/install.properties` looks to be wrong to me, the /en/ is not part of the chrome: URL, it is substituted when the chrome: URL is converted.

EDIT:

I don't see any [chrome registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_registration) entries in your chrome.manifest. They should look something like this:

```
locale gemgecko pl chrome/locale/pl
locale gemgecko en chrome/locale/en
```

Comment: Can you open `chrome://gemgecko/locale/install.properties` in the browser and does it display `extensions.gemgecko@gemius.pl.name=gemiusAudience study` and if it does can you find the preference in about:config and does it display `gemiusAudience study` correctly there too?

Comment: If you can't open the .properties file in the browser then

Comment: Ok, I've corrected chrome.manifest and pref.js. Now the browser display file content when I open `chrome://gemgecko/locale/install.properties` and the value in `about:config` is correct. But an extension manager displays the extension's name from install.rdf (when the file contains it), or doesn't load the extension (when the install.rdf file doesn't contain `name` field).

Comment: Yes, if the `install.rdf` file doesn't contain `<em:name></em:name>` (and the extension is not loaded). When the field is present in installation manifest, then the extension manager displays the extension's name from `install.rdf` not from `chrome://gemgecko/locale/install.properties`.

Comment: I can't see any more errors in the files you already posted. Would you mind posting your install.rdf too, just in case there's a problem there?

Comment: This works in Firefox 2.0, but it doesn't work in Firefox 1.5 because of https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=323436